# Is there a website where I can view XML documentation for NuGet packages?

Tags: nuget, documentation-generation

I have published a couple of NuGet packages (.NET class libraries). The packages include XML documentation file for each DLL. All packages are published on www.nuget.org and www.symbolsource.org.

Now, is there a website/service which will automatically generate (and host) documentation for my packages? I am picturing some sort of mini-site for my packages, where users can see all class definitions, their methods and related documentation from the XML file (basically something like MSDN but for my package)?

Ideally every time I publish a nuget package, I want to be able to go to www.SomeNugetDocumentationSite.com/packages/MyPackage and see MSDN-like documentation for my packages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed that [nudoq.org](http://www.nudoq.org/) does such thing for my [Pkcs11Interop package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pkcs11Interop/). I have never registered there or anything like that so I guess they are [generating documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Pkcs11Interop) from XML file which is present in the package.

However I still prefer to generate documentation with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) (which by the way uses the same inlined XML comments present in C# source code) and [host it by myself](http://pkcs11interop.net/doc/) because this way I can fully control the result.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Too bad it doesn't seem to have my packages, otherwise it's pretty neat.Would be interested in hearing of alternatives.